# What does "a rattled person" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [The Economist: Turmoil in Hong Kong](https://www.economist.com/briefing/2019/08/08/hong-kong-remains-crucially-important-to-mainland-china):

> On August 5th, at a press conference after two weeks hidden from public view, **a rattled Carrie Lam**, Hong Kong's chief executive, spoke of Asia’s financial hub being on the “verge of a very dangerous situation”.

Question 1: What does "a rattle person" mean here?

Question 2: Is the "a" here used as emphasis, like "a rattled President Obama"? (As an ell, this usage really confuses me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that several online dictionaries do NOT include the word as used here, so looking it up would have been confusing. Use this definition: [rattled](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rattled)

"Someone who's rattled feels confused and upset. When you're rattled, you're shaken and maybe a little fearful."

A person who's rattled might not be able to fully perform her duties or make decisions. She is distracted by the emergency.

EDIT: Addressing "a" as in "a rattled..."

We are introducing a descriptive phrase, an adjective. "A red engine" has a similar meaning; the engine is red. The "a" of "a red engine" is the indefinite article. However, with "a rattled Carrie Lam" we have the indefinite article introducing a specific person. I'm not sure that I can explain the rule for that, but it is common usage.

Using my own name, you could describe me as "a green Ed", "a rattled Ed", "a purple Ed". It's a way of introducing the adjective as it applies to the specific object or person. So, yes, "a" is providing emphasis.

Comment: Clear answer. Sir, could you help me with my another question which has been updated in my post?

Comment: Answer edited. Both are good questions!